# Proof that volume of cone is 1/3 that of a cylinder

Tags: geometry

I am trying to verfy the formula for "cone volume" calculation. It is not clear why cone volume is 1/3 of a cylinder volume with the same bottom size and height. Is there any proof of the fact that a cone's volume is one third of a cylinder's volume of the same height and bottom area?

Comment: The proof I know comes from calculus. There are lots of answers to "Can I prove this without calculus" at math.se. I *think* this is more a math question than a math education question.

Answer (score 5):

[Here is an answer on Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/644/1203732) that proves that the volume of a cone is $\dfrac{1}{3}$ the volume of a cylinder using only algebra and geometry. No calculus required.

**Note:** The proof relies on Cavalieri's Principle, which is probably intuitive enough for your purposes. But technically speaking, Cavalieri's Principle is usually proved using calculus (specifically, integrals). That said, there is an elementary proof of Cavalieri's Principle using only limits ([also on Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2556933/1203732)).